# Haskell infinite list of Pythagorean triples

Tags: haskell, recursion

Ive been trying this question for hours, still stuck on it. Can anyone help. Looking for suggestions:

Use a list comprehension to define a function **triples n** which returns a list of positive integer triples 
*(x, y, z)* all less than or equal to *n*, such that *x^2 + y^2 = z^2*

Do not produce duplicate triples or triples that are permutations of already produced triples.

Comment: Please show us your own attempt, even if it failed, so that we can see what you already know and how we can help you in the best way

Answer (score 1):

I had some code that kind of solves this problem already...

```
branchTriple = [
   \(a,b,c) -> (a - 2*b + 2*c, 2*a - b + 2*c, 2*a - 2*b + 3*c),
   \(a,b,c) -> (a + 2*b + 2*c, 2*a + b + 2*c, 2*a + 2*b + 3*c),
   \(a,b,c) -> (2*b - a + 2*c, b - 2*a + 2*c, 2*b - 2*a + 3*c)
 ]

primitiveTriples l = pt (3,4,5) where
  pt x = x : concatMap pt (filter l $ map ($ x) branchTriple)
allTriples l = let
  pt = primitiveTriples l
  mtriple (a,b,c) n = (a*n, b*n, c*n)
  multiples p = takeWhile l $ map (mtriple p) [1..]
  in concatMap multiples pt

usage n = allTriples (\(a,b,c) -> all (<= n) [a,b,c])
```

This code uses the [Tree of primitive Pythagorean triplets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples). I'll leave reformatting it to use list comprehensions as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: thanks for this, and for the link. (`c` is the largest in a triple, so `c <= n` should be enough). BTW, `map ($ x) branchTriple == branchTriple <*> [x]`.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks, I wrote this code a few months ago, I learned about applicatives a couple of weeks afterwards.

Comment: the list comprehension code actually turns up quite nice looking: ``usage n = [t | (a,b,c) <- primTriples n (3,4,5), 
 t <- [(a*k, b*k, c*k) | k <- [1..div n c]]] ;
primTriples n p = p : [t | q <- branchTriple <*> [p], 
 thrd q <= n,
 t <- primTriples n q] ; thrd (a,b,c) = c``. And with a function for one level down in the tree, `step n ts = [t | t <- branchTriple <*> ts, thrd t <= n]`, we can explore the tree level by level, `*Main> mapM_ print . takeWhile (not.null) . iterate (step 100) $ [(3,4,5)]` ==> 
`[(3,4,5)] 
[(5,12,13),(21,20,29),(15,8,17)] ...`.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
isSquare x = x == head (dropWhile (< x) squares)
  where squares = scanl1 (+) [1,3..]
```

and then define:

```
triples n = take n [(i,j,truncate (sqrt (fromIntegral (i*i+j*j) :: Double))) | i <- [1 ..], j <- [1 ..i-1], isSquare(i*i+j*j)]
```

In this case the first element is always larger than the second one.

If you want the elements of the tuples to be ordered as well, try:

```
triples n = take n [(j,i,truncate (sqrt (fromIntegral (i*i+j*j) :: Double))) | i <- [1..], j <- [1..i-1], isSquare(i*i+j*j)]
```

Testing if a number is square is quite inefficient with the first method, you can replace it with this one:

```
isSquare x = let x' = truncate $ sqrt (fromIntegral x :: Double) in x'*x' == x
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this fit the bill?

```
ghci> [(x,y,z) | z<-[1..], x<-[1..z], y<-[1..z], x^2+y^2==z^2, x<y ]
   [(3,4,5),(6,8,10),(5,12,13),(9,12,15),(8,15,17),(12,16,20),
    (7,24,25),(15,20,25),(10,24,26),(20,21,29),(18,24,30),(16,30,34),
    (21,28,35),(12,35,37),(15,36,39),(24,32,40),(9,40,41), 
       ....^Cinterrupted
```